# Ambiguity in a corollary in limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, real-numbers

I'm reading Steven G. Krantz's Real analysis and foundations when I came across this Corollary.

Corollary 3.2: Let $S$ be a set of real numbers which is bounded above and below. Let $\beta$ be its supremum and $\alpha$ its infimum. If $\epsilon>0$ then there are $s,t\in S$ such that $|s-\beta|<\epsilon$ and $|t-\alpha|<\epsilon$.

Shouldn't it be "Let $S$ be a bounded interval of real numbers"?. Is there something I'm missing here? Surely, if $S$ is a "bounded set" of reals we can have $S=\{1,2,3,...,10\}$ and set $\epsilon=0.5$, which makes the above corollary redundant.

Comment: Well the equivalent phrase is "Let $S$ be a non-empty bounded subset of $\mathbb {R} $". The corollary is an immediate consequence of the definition of supremum and infimum. The corollary is trivial if $\alpha, \beta$ also lie in $S$. The supremum / infimum are an interesting idea only when don't lie in the set under discussion.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh yes, but is the statement "Let $S$ be a set of real numbers which is bounded above and below" correct?

Comment: The meaning of that statement is same as the statement in my comment. A set is said to be bounded if it is both bounded above and bounded below. This is fairly standard terminology. Do you see any ambiguity here?

Comment: I don't understand your issue with this corollary. Yes, indeed we ***can*** have $S=\{1,2,3,\ldots,10\}$. But the fact that we ***can*** have something doesn't mean that we ***have to*** have that something. This corollary is as true for this $S$ as it is for any other (non-empty) bounded subsets of reals. Maybe it's not so interesting for this $S$, but it is for other examples of $S$; and it is very useful in general.

Comment: I would suggest you to write definition of supremum infimum in your natural language without using any mathematical symbols. That will clarify what these mean and then the corollary will be obvious and you might think that mentioning such corollaries explicitly is a redundancy in analysis books.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh and zipirovich think of it like this. The corollary says that $S$ be a set of reals which is bounded above and below. So I choose $S=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. Now the Infimum of my set is 1, the supremum is 5. The corollary guarantees for all $\epsilon>0$ there are elements $s,$ in $S$ such that $|s-1|<\epsilon$ and $|t-5|<\epsilon$. If I set $\epsilon=0.5$, I can't find elements in $S$ which satisfy the above. But the corollary guarantees that I can find. Why?

Comment: Well those elements are 1 and 5. What's the problem with them?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I feel like a fool. Thanks

Comment: Don't feel that way. Perhaps you have encountered a scenario in real life when you have a spoon in your hand and yet you are searching (asking others also) for it in your entire house.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh That comforts me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  For instance, let $S = \{1/n : n \in [1,\infty) \cap \Bbb{Z} \}$ is a set and the stated corollary is nontrivial at its infimum.

Another is $S = \{\arctan(n) : n \in \Bbb{Z} \}$ for which the corollary is nontrivial at both its supremum and infimum.